# Does the Laos ANZ bank help with replacement ATM/VISA cards for Australian and New Zealand ANZ bank customers?

Tags: money, payment-cards, australian-citizens, laos, new-zealand-citizens

On my last legal day in Thailand I realized my ANZ ATM card was missing. I was obliged to cross the border on that day so couldn't stay and leisurely try to resolve the problem.

A series of events led to the unexpected cancellation of my backup VISA credit card with the same bank leaving me with no access to my funds.

ANZ is a bank based in Australia and New Zealand. But it turns out [it also exists in Laos](https://www.anz.com.au/laos/en/about-us/our-company/ANZ-Laos/).

In the past I've had bad experiences getting replacement cards while overseas. This time will the two banks cooperate to make it easy or stick to some painful "da rules is da rules"?

Comment: Agree to HalaBi. I would be surprised if ANZ treats NZ customers differently from AU customers.

Comment: I think this question should be asked in [Personal Finance and Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In my experience with big multinational companies they can be very separate sharing only a name. But it depends totally on the company, its size, how it is structured, what it's there for, and its official policies. ANZ is probably here because Australian companies are involved in the local industry. But they may have special things they claim to support such as customers from the "home" countries.

Comment: @hippietrail my point was, people there would know better how to answer it, I believe there are bankers and the like in that site. If it is on-topic or not, I guess it is because it is a problem that might face any traveler from the [40 countries](http://www.anz.com/international/en/) with ANZ branches.

Comment: @HaLaBi: I think you're not getting my point that those 40 countries are equal, it's just not like Citibank or HSBC. I also doubt it's a problem bankers and financial types care much about unless they're involved specifically in travellers' finance and banking. I doubt people into the finance world care about company policies not related to money but to customer support.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer only so far ...**

I visited the Vientiane branch today.

[image: ANZ bank in Vientiane, Laos]

They use the term "Commercial Bank" in their name here and there are only two branches in the entire country so it's not competing with the typical banks aimed at Lao people's savings and loans.

- The companies are separate and a Laos branch cannot request replacement cards for somebody who holds an account in Australia.
- They would not call ANZ for me in Australia, at least partially because of the long-distance rate equivalent to about $3 per minute.
- *I forgot that ANZ Australia allows reverse charge calls from customers overseas - so I could've specifically asked them if they would do that for me.*
- They **can** receive my replacement cards for me for me to drop by and pick up. This was a huge cost in the last country I needed replacement cards so is good in itself. I do not know whether there would be a fee for them to be sent anyway.

I very much doubt any of this would be a problem if I were travelling in New Zealand or if a New Zealander had this problem in Australia.

---

Just a note that currently, late 2023, this bank is now Allianz but still seems to have some relationship to ANZ according to the smaller text on the new sign. There are no ANZ ATMs in Vientiane any more.